# php pdo: it it possbile to have a DBMS agnostic 'describe table'?

Tags: php, pdo, database

I have a script that parse the database and create php classes to work with that db. (zend-db-model-generator). is there a way to in php to have a DBMS agonstic commands so on each type of db it will return the table structure ?

so it doesn't matter if i use the pdo driver once for mysql and once for postgresql, it will still return the table structure.

the only solution that i see for now is to get the db type and to switch on each db type and execute the appropriate command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the same SQL query, unfortunatly, doesn't seem quite possible, as far as I can tell...

About your idea of going through the database to extract informations about each table to generate some PHP classes, that's one of the things that [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) (the most famous PHP ORM) does.

If you download it, and take a look at the classes in `Doctrine/Import/[DatabaseType].php`, you'll see this is done differently for each kind of database.

For instance, for MySQL, the following piece of code is used in `Doctrine_Import_Mysql` :

```
'listTableFields' => 'DESCRIBE %s',
```

On the other hand, for PostgreSQL, you've got the following, in `Doctrine_Import_Pgsql` :

```
'listTableColumns'     => "SELECT
                            a.attnum,
                            a.attname AS field,
                            t.typname AS type,
                            format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod) AS complete_type,
                            a.attnotnull AS isnotnull,
                            (SELECT 't'
                              FROM pg_index
                              WHERE c.oid = pg_index.indrelid
                              AND a.attnum = ANY (pg_index.indkey)
                              AND pg_index.indisprimary = 't'
                            ) AS pri,
                            (SELECT pg_attrdef.adsrc
                              FROM pg_attrdef
                              WHERE c.oid = pg_attrdef.adrelid
                              AND pg_attrdef.adnum=a.attnum
                            ) AS default
                      FROM pg_attribute a, pg_class c, pg_type t
                      WHERE c.relname = %s
                            AND a.attnum > 0
                            AND a.attrelid = c.oid
                            AND a.atttypid = t.oid
                      ORDER BY a.attnum",
```

Not that easy, it seems ^^

And, farther down each class, there is a method called `listTableColumns` -- which is not the same for each database type...

So I'm guessing things will, unfortunatly, not be as simple as you hoped...

But, as a sidenote : maybe you could use Doctrine for that part of your project -- might be faster than re-inventing the wheel ;-)

Comment: hi. thanks for the update. i have my own project called zend-db-model-generator, it's on google code. wanna improve it a bit.

Comment: OK about having your own project :-) ;; Have fun !